# How to overwrite closure without overwriting the whole parent method in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to inherit from a method to modify a closure. I know that inheriting from a closure in order to modify it is not possible as it is defined locally in the method, but I am looking for a workaround to completely overwrite the code of the closure, like if I were doing a new one, and without overwriting the rest of the method. The problem is that I need to name the new closure like the old one, because it is called a few lines below.

Example:

```
def parent_method(self):

    def _closure(self, x, y, z):
        ...
        return res
    
    ... a lot of code lines ...

    variable_1 = _closure(self, x, y, z)

    ... a lot of code lines which use variable_1 ...
```

I need to replace what `_closure` returns, but I have to modify no line from the left of the code lines. The left lines of the method must do exactly what they do now.

The only solution I know is to inherit from `parent_method` and replace its whole code (just to modify the `_closure` return), which wouldn't be a good solution since I'm developing for an ERP and there will be many modules which will inherit this method too, and this way I will be destroying their functionality.

Any idea of how to manage that workaround? Or is that just impossible?

Comment: maybe use it as another private method in class and not as closure. you can use it same as other method using `self.__clousre` instead of `_clousre`

Comment: You can't "inherit" from a method. You can't "override" or change a function defined inside of the other function same as you can't change a local variable from outside without changing the logic of the function

Comment: @sahasrara62 the ERP source code is what it is, I can't change that. They decided to do a closure and I have to deal with that. If I "extract" the closure and turn it into a private class method I need to change the whole code of `_parent_method` in order to change the line which calls the closure to calculate `variable_1`. And that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @Yevhen Kuzmovych so I have to overwrite the whole code of `parent_method` to change one line, don't I? That is a problem because other modules will modify the method using `super`, but those modules can be installed or not, depending on the needs of the companies which use the ERP. I will be destroying their modifications since I'm overwriting the whole method. And I can't add their modifications to my method too since those modules could be useless for some users.

Comment: [software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) you may get better solution here, code is tighty coupled so you need to modify it . otherwise create a new function parameter in function call and a new method in class, and based on usage, if this modified result require then change code in variable1 who based on codiiton call clouser inside  method  or class method, with this you can maintain existing flow and implent new feature

Comment: That's a nasty problem. A much hacky way would be to find a function call between the closure definition and it getting called (where you indicate there are a few lines) and monkey-patch it with a custom function, that inspects the stack frame to change the reference of the closure to something else, then let pass through. But it's not something I would like to see in code I have to maintain. Much better would be to change it upstream so that the closure is a proper method, that you could cleanly and simply redefine.